# Formulário duplicado usando ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Senhores, boa tarde!
Possuo o formulário onde cadastro minha informação perfeitamente. Uso Ajax pq carrego apenas um conteúdo da pagina após o cadastro, e não ela toda. Funciona normal, o problema consiste se eu for efetuar um novo cadastro, ele duplica o que eu to inserindo, como se enviasse o form duas vezes. Aí se eu for fazer uma terceira inserção, ele duplica o a inserção a quantidade de vezes que foi inserida anteriormente. Se eu der F5 na pagina, funciona normal também. O que pode ser? Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

A função que uso para efetuar a inserção é essa:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(document).on('submit', '#form_nova_categoria', function ()
    {
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../../../acotacao/admin/cadastro/mercadologico/acoes/nova_categoria.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data === "ok") {


                    $("#collapse_nova_categoria").collapse('toggle');
                    $(".conteudo_pagina").hide();
                    $("#conteudo").load("../../../../acotacao/admin/cadastro/mercadologico/categorias.php").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#msg-ok").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                        $("#msg-ok").slideUp(500);
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#collapse_nova_categoria").collapse('toggle');
                    $(".conteudo_pagina").hide();
                    $("#conteudo").load("../../../../acotacao/admin/cadastro/mercadologico/categorias.php").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#msg-erro").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                        $("#msg-erro").slideUp(500);
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#collapse_nova_categoria").collapse('toggle');
                $(".conteudo_pagina").hide();
                $("#conteudo").load("../../../../acotacao/admin/cadastro/mercadologico/categorias.php").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#msg-erro").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                    $("#msg-erro").slideUp(500);
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Aguardo, e desde já agradeço!

Comment: por acaso a insercao que esta duplicando é essa: `$("#conteudo").load('...')`?

Comment: Bom, essa linha se refere ao recarregamento da div que quero que atualize. Pq como eu disse, não to dando refresh na página, ele insere e atualiza a div mostrando a inserção que foi feita.

Comment: Acabei de retirar essa linha que você mencionou @NeuberOliveira e o erro persiste.

Comment: "carrego apenas um conteúdo da pagina após o cadastro" qual o trecho de codigo que faz esse carregamento? Ate onde percebo a unica coisa que esta sendo carregada apos o submit é com esse `$.load()` posta tambem o trecho que esta sendo duplicado, da um pouco mais de contexto.